# How can I programmatically create new sites in IIS 6?

Tags: iis-6, wmi

Currently whenever a new subdomain is created for the site, a new host header value needs to be added manually in IIS for it to work (needs to work with and without SSL). Is there a way to set host header value via API so that subdomains can be created without human intervention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IIS 6, WMI will do the trick. Here's an example on Technet/MSDN:

> Creating Sites and Virtual
>   Directories, and Setting Properties
>   Using WMI
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524913

-Oisin

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Full instructions on how to do this can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/addhostheader.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Check this blogpost: [Creating a new website programmatically on IIS using ASP.NET and C#](http://stweet.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/creating-a-new-website-programmatically-on-iis-using-asp-net/)